# ios: retrieve values from nsdictonary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I get values as shown below.

How can I get particular values of ABC, NI, NTI, SRNI and TTT?

```
(
 {
     ABC = A;
     NI = 5;
     NTI = I;
     SRNI = 12R00109;
     TTT = Pqr;
 }
)
```

Comment: `[dico valueForKey:@"ABC"];`  ? if you have a NSDictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *Str=[yourDic valueForKey:@"ABC"];
```

Comment: Try to use modern objective-C: yourDic[@"ABC"]

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"ABC": @"A",
                       @"NI" : @5,
                       @"NTI": @"I"};

NSLog(@"ABC =  %@, NI = %@, NTI = %@" , dict[@"ABC"], dict[@"NI"], dict[@"NTI"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you have an Array and dictionary so you can retrieve like this

```
NSString *strABC = [[yourArray objectatindex:0] valueforkey:@"ABC"];

NSString *strNI = [[yourArray objectatindex:0] valueforkey:@"NI"];
```

Comment: Can you format your code snippets